# Infer 2D transformation from its jacobian

Tags: integration, transformation, jacobian

I am looking for 2D transformation that lead to the following jacobian :

$$\frac{1}{1-xy}$$

I first tried with usual transformation (polar, afine, bipolar, elliptic and hyperbolic) but no success on it. After also trying some manual trials in wolframalpha I arrived to this best trial:

$$(x,y) \mapsto (\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-xy}}, -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-xy}})$$

which leads to jacobian:

$$\frac{1}{(1-xy)^2}$$

I am looking for an example, despite a complete characterization (that means integrating partial differential system) could be also useful if provide further constraints in the possible solutions set (I guess there are infinite).

Comment: Try $r=\log(1-x y), s = \frac{1}{2}\log(x/y)$

Comment: The radicands should be {in curly braces}, not (in parentheses) in order to extend the root sign across them.

Comment: Thanks joriki. Done now.

Comment: Yes Dr. Wolfgang, it fits with requirements. Despite I would like to know another one if exists. Thanks!